# Live SDK iOS 5.6 version

Tags: ios, sdk, live

I checked out the library, I don't see any API to perform "search" on server.

Is the search not supported ?

Can anyone suggest some alternative ?

Library reference is here and it does not mention anything about performing "search" on server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631816.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by using following path

NSString* path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"me/Skydrive/search?q=%@",searchText];